# Minimize and restore window using Send Messages in MFC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I am learning MFC and I am trying to learn about sending messages. I have been searching for days but haven't been able to figure out what exactly it is i need.

I have two dialogue boxes and one of them has a button that is supposed to minimize or restore the other window. I have been able to figure out how to use pointers to accomplish this but i would like to convert it to a SendMessage function.

Here is the current code i use with pointers...

*Window2.cpp*

```
void CWindow2::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    if (m_windowOne != NULL) {
        if (buttonstate == 0) {
            m_windowOne->ShowWindow(SW_MINIMIZE);
            buttonstate = 1;
        }
        else {
            m_windowOne->ShowWindow(SW_RESTORE);
            buttonstate = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

If someone could explain how to get similar function by using messages instead of pointers that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No need to send messages, `ShowWindow` is fine. But if you want to insist, try [`SendMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t64sseb3.aspx) with [`WM_SYSCOMMAND`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I have been trying to figure it out with SendMessage and SW_SYSCOMMAND but i cant't seem to figure out how to specify the other window. I can make it function for the window containing the button but thats not what i need.

Comment: `m_windowOne->SendMessage(WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MINIMIZE);`, but as I wrote before, it's pointless.

Comment: Is that not just using a pointer? How does that differ from 'm_windowOne->ShowWindow(SW_MINIMIZE);' Sorry for all the questions im just trying to fully understand this

Comment: You want to send a message to the window corresponding to `m_windowOne`, well that's the way to specify the window you want.

Comment: Okay thank you for the clarification!

Comment: You can also use the raw Win32 `SendMessage` function rather than the MFC `SendMessage` function: `::SendMessage(m_windowOne->m_hWnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MINIMIZE, 0, 0);` but it's pointless to use the raw Win32 function rather than the corresponding MFC function.

Comment: Okay i think that is where my confusion came from. Most of what i was able to find was in that style but was using `HWND_BROADCAST` or other methods

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly different context but it conveys the priniples:

```
void CSomeDialog::OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if ((nID & 0x0000FFF0) == SC_MINIMIZE)
    {
        // Minimizing, post to main dialogue also.
        AfxGetMainWnd()->ShowWindow(SW_MINIMIZE);
    }
    else if ((nID & 0x0000FFF0) == SC_RESTORE && IsIconic())
    {
        // Restoring, post to main dialogue also.
        AfxGetMainWnd()->ShowWindow(SW_RESTORE);
    }

    CDialogEx::OnSysCommand(nID, lParam);
}
```

In the above scenario, whenever dialog CSomeDialog is minimized or restored it feeds this to the main application window too.

If you have the dialog in question as a variable in your class then `ShowWindow(...)` should be sufficient.